# Word usage of 'query'

Tags: word-choice, verbs, vocabulary

Is there anything wrong in the following sentence :

> I **queried** Sonia about her Personal Computer.

The sentence is akin to :

> I **asked** Sonia about her Personal Computer.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. There's no difference in that sentence from "I asked Sonia...".

It just sounds a bit formal and stilted.

Edit: This is from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/query?o=100074), the meaning of "query".

> to ask or inquire about: No one queried his presence.

It's synonymous with "ask", and can be interchanged, as you like it. :)

Comment: Was there any mistake in my query ?

Comment: Your query was fine. I just did a little bit of capitalisation.

Comment: Do you know, why did I get a +1 for the question?

Comment: You don't like it? :)

Comment: :- Of course, I do like it. I can repeat the same and earn more pluses. :)

Comment: Personally, I would never bother to capitalize personal computer unless I was using the acronym. I would be more likely to say, "I asked Sonya about her PC" or "...about her computer."